# Product of measurable numerical functions is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $f: X \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is said to be measurable if and only if the preimage of an open subset of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is measurable in $X$. The topology on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is defined as follows: the open subsets are unions of intervals of the form $\left [ -\infty , a \right [$, $\left ]  a, b \right [$ and  $\left ]  a, \infty \right ]$. It can be shown that the usual criterions for measurablity still apply. Define $\infty.(-\infty) =-\infty$, $\infty.\infty =\infty$, $(-\infty).(-\infty )=\infty$ and $0.(\pm \infty)=0$. I'm looking for a satisfactory proof for the measurablity of the product of measubrale numerical functions. I'm aware of the standard approach, but I find the standard proofs rather unsatisfactory patchwork.

With standard approach, I mean something like this: Use one of the usual criterions to prove that $f.g$ is measurable, for instance, prove that $(f.g)^{-1}(\left ]  a, \infty \right ])$ is measurable for every real $a$. Start with proving (I can do all that) that $f^2$ is measurable if $f$ is, that $f+g$ is measurable if $f$ and $g$ are (attribute a fixed but arbitrary value to $f+g$ where it is not defined). Then finally (e.g. for $a>0$) observe that $(f.g)^{-1}(\left ]  a, \infty \right ])= (f^{-1}(\infty)\bigcap g^{-1}(\left ]  0, \infty \right ]))\bigcup (g^{-1}(\infty)\bigcap f^{-1}(\left ]  0, \infty \right ]))\bigcup (f^{-1}(-\infty)\bigcap g^{-1}(\left [  -\infty, 0 \right [))\bigcup (g^{-1}(-\infty)\bigcap f^{-1}(\left [  -\infty, 0 \right [))\bigcup  \left \{ x \in X: f(x) \text{ and } g(x) \text{ are finite }   \text{ and } \dfrac{1}{4}((f(x)+g(x))^2 - (f(x)-g(x))^2) > a\right \}$

The fact that the last of these sets is measurable should be an evident consequence of the measurability of squares and sums of measurable numerical functions, but I find that not very convincing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out for myself. Proving that $  \left \{ x \in X: f(x) \text{ and } g(x) \text{ are finite }   \text{ and } \dfrac{1}{4}((f(x)+g(x))^2 - (f(x)-g(x))^2) > a\right \} $ is measurable. Replace $f$ and $g$ with $\tilde{f}$ and  $\tilde{g}$ (if necessary), by replacing infinite function values with an $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. It is easy to prove that $\tilde{f}$ and  $\tilde{g}$ are also measurable (using one of the criterions), hence $(\tilde{f}+\tilde{g})^{2}$ and $(\tilde{f}-\tilde{g})^2$ too, without the issues of not being defined everywhere. Hence $  \left \{ x \in X:  \dfrac{1}{4}((\tilde{f}(x)+\tilde{g}(x))^2 - (\tilde{f}(x)-\tilde{g}(x))^2) > a\right \} $  is a measurable set in $X$. Now observe that $  \left \{ x \in X:  \dfrac{1}{4}((\tilde{f}(x)+\tilde{g}(x))^2 - (\tilde{f}(x)-\tilde{g}(x))^2) > a\right \} \bigcap f^{-1}(\left ]-\infty,\infty\right [) \bigcap g^{-1}(\left ]-\infty,\infty\right [)= \left \{ x \in X: f(x) \text{ and } g(x) \text{ are finite }   \text{ and } \dfrac{1}{4}((f(x)+g(x))^2 - (f(x)-g(x))^2) > a\right \}$

and you are done.